# How do you create a wait function in JavaScript that allows you to run things in the background like audio?

Tags: javascript, audio, delay, wait, alerts

I created this as a simple wait script but the most it will do is freeze the entire script for **time** period of seconds.

```
function wait(time)
{
var x = 0;
var y = time * 500000000;
while (x<y)
{
x++
}
}
```

What I need is a code that can delay the script so I can play a sound because my script loops and has a crap load of Alerts so the sound does not play until the script is over.

This is the script I used to play the sound:

```
<div id="dummy"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function playSound(sound)
{
if (sound==1)
{
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = '<embed type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.myinstants.com/media/sounds/sound-8.mp3" autoplay="true" hidden="true" width="0" height="0" loop="false">';
}
}
</script>
```

And yes, I called *playSound(1)* in another script.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a function that blocks (i.e. forces the caller to wait for it to complete) in Javascript without freezing the UI completely.

Look at `setTimeout`, callbacks, and possibly Promises as ways to perform these actions asynchronously.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: There is one problem though, the function is called in a WHILE statement, so, the only thing I can do about it is nothing. If I use setTimeout, it will only delay what the argument is (Example: setTimeout(function(){playSound(1);},2000) will only delay playSound(1)) therefor, the while statement will continue and there will be nothing to delay it so the sound will continue.

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, i believe you would like to use the setTimeout method.
You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and there you will find some examples.

Here is something short

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(playSound, 1000, sound);
    }
and call it wherever you need
    </script>
```

Comment: is there a way to make the entire thread wait as well too instead of sending the rest of it in the function?

Comment: nvm there are async functions, u can await the resolution of a promise